# Divide list of numbers into 3 groups in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a list of numbers, [1:9], that I need to divide three groups. Each group must contain at least one number. I need to enumerate all of the combinations (i.e. order does not matter). Ideally, the output is a x by 3 array. Any ideas of how to do this in matlab?

Comment: So what would be the result? Just the number of ways?

Comment: show an example of input and an output.

Comment: I solved it, but can't post it yet since I am a new member. The output is a 5154x3 cell array with all of the possible ways that the numbers can be divided.

Comment: Each of the 9 elements of input x can be in any of the 3 arrays, so you must have 3^9 possibilities, that's 19683, not 5154. Each possibility contains 3 arrays of course

Comment: 5154? How do you get that number?

Comment: 3^9 produces empty groups, each group has to have at least 1 number in it. 3^9 also produces all of the permutations and I need the combinations. This is reflected in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
x = 1:9;
n = length(x);
T=3;

out = {};
%// Loop over all possible solutions
for k=1:T^n
    s = dec2base(k, T, n);
    out{k}{T} = [];
    for p=1:n
        grpIndex = str2num(s(p))+1;
        out{k}{grpIndex} = [out{k}{grpIndex} x(p)];
    end
end

%// Print result. size of out is the number of ways to divide the input. out{k} contains 3 arrays with the values of x
out
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want. I'm assuming that the division in groups is "monotonous", that is, first come the elements of the first group, then those of the second etc.

```
n = 9; %// how many numbers
k = 3; %// how many groups
b = nchoosek(1:n-1,k-1).'; %'// "breaking" points
c = diff([ zeros(1,size(b,2)); b; n*ones(1,size(b,2)) ]); %// result
```

Each column of `c` gives the *sizes* of the `k` groups:

```
c =

  Columns 1 through 23

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     1     2     3     4     5     6     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     1
     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     6     5     4     3     2     1     5     4     3     2     1     4     3     2     1     3

  Columns 24 through 28

     5     5     6     6     7
     2     3     1     2     1
     2     1     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces what I was looking for. The function nchoosekr_rec() is shown below as well.

```
for x=1:7
    numgroups(x)=x;
end

c=nchoosekr_rec(numgroups,modules);
i=1;
d=zeros(1,modules);
for x=1:length(c(:,1))
    c(x,modules+1)=sum(c(x,1:modules));
    if c(x,modules+1)==length(opt_mods)
        d(i,:)=c(x,1:modules);
        i=i+1;
    end
end

numgroups=[];
for x=1:length(opt_mods)
    numgroups(x)=x;
end


count=0;

for x=1:length(d(:,1))
    combos=combnk(numgroups,d(x,1));
    for y=1:length(combos(:,1))
        for z=1:nchoosek(9-d(x,1),d(x,2))
            new_mods{count+z,1}=combos(y,:);
            numgroups_temp{count+z,1}=setdiff(numgroups,new_mods{count+z,1});
        end
        count=count+nchoosek(9-d(x,1),d(x,2));
    end
end

count=0;

for x=1:length(d(:,1))

    for y=1:nchoosek(9,d(x,1))
        combos=combnk(numgroups_temp{count+1},d(x,2));
        for z=1:length(combos(:,1))
            new_mods{count+z,2}=combos(z,:);
            new_mods{count+z,3}=setdiff(numgroups_temp{count+z,1},new_mods{count+z,2});
        end
        count=count+length(combos(:,1));
    end
end





  function y = nchoosekr_rec(v, n)

   if n == 1
      y = v;
   else
      v = v(:);
      y = [];
      m = length(v);
      if m == 1
         y = zeros(1, n);
         y(:) = v;
      else
         for i = 1 : m
         y_recr = nchoosekr_rec(v(i:end), n-1);
         s_repl = zeros(size(y_recr, 1), 1);
         s_repl(:) = v(i);
         y = [ y ; s_repl, y_recr ];
         end
      end
   end
```